# Android MediaPlayer onError delegate method never called

Tags: java, android, stream, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have an Android app currently in production. This app streams remote live audio files using the MediaPlayer class of the Android SDK.

I set an errorListener on my mediaplayer like this:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

But I never get in the following delegate method (according to Google Analytics, none of my thousand users get in this delegate method) :

```
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extras) {

        GoogleAnalytics.trackAction("MainActivity", "Streaming onError", "onError what = " + what + " extras = " + extras);         

        return true;
    }
```

My question is : why I never get in the OnError method ? Is there a bug in the MediaPlayer class ?

Comment: If you found the answer please share it.

Comment: please share the answer...!